# file_get_contents sometimes does not find texts

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'am new to PHP, so please be nice :)

Sometimes file_get_contents does its job and sometimes not. I have build a simple check for URLs, if they exist, on webpages. But the problem is, that even the URL exist for sure (manually checked the sourcecode), file_get_contents and preg_match do not find it. I can't figure out why. Here's the code:

```
$page = $URL_that_should_be_checked;
$checkurl = str_replace("/", "\/", $checkurl);
$page = file_get_contents($userpage);
$checkurl = "/".$checkurl."/";
$report = preg_match($checkurl, $page);
```

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$page = file_get_contents($userpage);

$report = preg_match('/' . preg_quote($checkurl) . '/', $page);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've done a test and this solution. But still not in my main script. Damn :)

Comment: I think you need to add some logging in your main script to find out the reason of wrong result

Answer (score 2):

It's rather difficult to follow your code.

Did you check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) page and note that special characters may need to be encoded with the `urlencode()` function?

On this line `$checkurl = str_replace("/", "\/", $checkurl);` the variable `$checkurl` does not appear to have a definition.

On this line `$userpage` does not seem to be defined. Only `$page` is defined in the code you've provided.

It looks like you're doing a lot of work to set up a preg_match and `$report` its value. It's unclear why you need to fetch the page during this process.

Also, do you have [allow_url_fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) set to true? Are you getting any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the PHP Function preg_quote to parse the URL to your preg_match Function. Example:

```
$checkurl = preg_quote($checkurl);
```

See: http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-quote.php

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your code is doing.

You do

```
$page = $URL_that_should_be_checked;
```

but two lines later do

```
$page = file_get_contents($userpage);
```

without ever having set $userpage.